# How to use ampl.lic in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, solver, ampl, baron

I have the licence of some solvers and I want to use these solvers in Pyomo. The licence file is ampl.lic and my machine is Macbook.
I have an executable file for Baron solver which is only for demo and when I run it for my model I get a licence error. My question is how can I use ampl.lic file to use this solver?

Comment: More information is needed to determine the cause of the license error. To get started, copy all of the contents of the ampl.lic file into your question, and also all lines of the error message that you are seeing.

Comment: @4er The licence doesn't have any error. I downloaded an executable Baron that is trial version in the site and it is obvious that it doesn't work for a large problem with a lot of constraints. I have also an ampl licence file but I dont know how to use this ampl licence to run the solver in Pyomo.

Comment: Your license file should be named ampl.lic. Move or copy it into the same folder as the baron program file, which is named "baron" and has a black square icon. Then repeat your steps to use the BARON solver. If you still have a problem, then to get more help, it is very important that you do the following:

(1) Copy all lines of your ampl.lic file into your question. If you have more then one file named ampl.lic, copy all lines of each file into your question.

(2) Copy all lines of the error message that you're seeing, into your question. It is important to provide the exact message.

Comment: @4er Thank you for your reply. I realised that the licence had some issue. I am waiting for a new licence.